# How to add "code" in Response Body of IHttpActionResult return BadRequest(Message)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I am returning BadRequest("Failed Invalid Product Id"), which returns me Response code 400 and Response Body

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Failed Invalid Product Id"
     }
}
```

How can I send the Response code 400 in the Response Body so I get Response Body Like:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Failed Invalid Product Id"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, with out testing it:

```
return Content((HttpStatusCode)400, "Failed Invalid Product Id");
```

If you really want to have customized way to do it than you need to extend `IHttpActionResult` implementation with your own class like the following example which is inspired from this [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2119762.aspx?Web%20API%202%20return%20custom%20error%20object):

```
public class ErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly Error _error;
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;

    public ErrorResult(Error error, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _error = error;
        _request = request;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var err = new Error()
        {
            Code = _error.Code,
            Message = _error.Message
        };

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<Error>(err, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
            RequestMessage = _request
        };
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}

public class Error
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var err = new Error()
{
    Code = "400",
    Message = "Failed Invalid Product Id"
};

return new ErrorResult(err, Request);
```

This will error return:

[image]